# HasAndBelongsToMany rails class build method calling super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to chase down what I believe to be a bug in the has_and_belongs_to_many method in Rails. The gotcha is that I am using an irregular pluralization for my class.  We'll call this class StreetOfCars. I have the irregular pluralization set up correctly as documented below. The class names are only examples, the important thing is the irregularity of StreetOfCars and that it ends with an 's'. I have two questions.

1. What the heck is going on here?
2. Where is the super finally landing?

Please let me know if you need any other information.

```
StreetOfCars.reflect_on_assocation(:cities).options[:join_table]
#=> 'cities_streets_of_cars'

City.reflect_on_assocation(:streets_of_cars).options[:join_table]
#=> 'cities_streets_of_car'

class StreetOfGold
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
end

class City
 has_and_belongs_to_many :streets_of_gold
end

#File config/initializers/inflections.rb
   ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
     inflect.irregular 'street_of_gold', 'streets_of_gold'
   end

# File activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_and_belongs_to_many.rb, line 7
  class HasAndBelongsToMany < CollectionAssociation
    def build
      reflection = super
      check_validity(reflection)
      define_destroy_hook
      reflection
    end
  end

# File activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb, line 21
  class CollectionAssociation < Association
    def build
      wrap_block_extension
      reflection = super
      CALLBACKS.each { |callback_name| define_callback(callback_name) }
      reflection
    end
  end
# File active_record/associations/association.rb
  class Association
    # build is not defined in this class.
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `:class` directive in your associations instead of trying to trick with the inflector? I've seen these types of problems before and there was much less sweat and tears just "giving in" to using `:class` instead of trying to bend the inflector to do what you want.

Comment: You are correct, you can either pass in the :class_name option or the :join_table option and override the default Rails behavior. I'm more interested in understanding how 'super' is being used so I can trace down the bug in the code.

Comment: Ok..yeah. I suspected as much ;) That's good. However can't help you much there..other than I'd try to run it under ruby debugger and trace through the code and see where it ends up (if you didn't try it yet)..

Comment: Btw. I downloaded rails from github, and there we have `active_record/associations/builder/association.rb`, where `build` is defined.

Comment: awesome, that's the file I was missing.